# Undefined is not a function is CoffeeScript / Angular / Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, coffeescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I've written a short unit test based on the example from the [Angular unit-testing documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing). I've tried to create a jsfiddle with no luck, so please bear with me.

```
# app definition
app = module 'myApp', []
.controller 'myCtrl', ['$scope', ($scope) ->$scope.foo = 'foo']

# test
describe 'myCtrl tests', () ->
  beforeEach module 'myApp'
  $controller = undefined

  beforeEach inject (_$controller_) ->
    $controller = _$controller_

  describe 'myCtrl', () ->
    it 'should not throw an error', () ->
      $scope = {}
      controller = $controller 'myCtrl',{$scope: $scope}
      expect ($scope.foo).toEqual 'foo'
```

When I run this test, I get "TypeError: undefined is not a function"
for $scope.foo and the test fails.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following two lines of CoffeeScript code:

```
expect ($scope.foo).toEqual 'foo'  # line 1
expect($scope.foo).toEqual 'foo'   # line 2
```

You may expect that these produce the same JavaScript code, but they do not:

```
expect($scope.foo.toEqual('foo')) // line 1
expect($scope.foo).toEqual('foo') // line 2
```

From the example you linked to, it's easy to see that what you want is the second line, not the former.

Comment: Brilliant! That was it. I knew it had to be a CoffeeScript gremlin.

Answer (score 2):

Your

```
expect ($scope.foo).toEqual 'foo'
```

is being transpiled to:

```
expect($scope.foo.toEqual('foo'));
```

So, javascript thinks $scope.foo is a function (which it is not). Remember, a space in CoffeeScript signals that you're passing a parameter to a function.

What it seems you want is either of the following:

```
expect $scope.foo
    .toEqual 'foo'
```

or

```
expect($scope.foo).toEqual 'foo'
```

These will both become:

```
expect($scope.foo).toEqual('foo');
```